# React Typescript: Antd Checkbox value not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Hello im trying to fill the Checkbox value with my state but it dont accept it.

The Checkbox Code:

```
<Form.Item label="Aktiv" >
    <Checkbox value={this.state.selectedRecord.active} />
</Form.Item>
```

Value of the state selectedRecord:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing it to this.

```html
<Checkbox checked={this.state.selectedRecord.active} />
```